# Tile selection on a 2D ortho fake infinite grid

Tags: c#, 2d, game-development, monogame, tile

**I cannot find the right offset to get the tile that is selected on a simulated fake grid.**

---

I draw a grid on a texture (monogame renderTarget) that I offset in the center :

```
GRID_CENTER_X = (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) - ((GRID_WIDTH * TILE_WIDTH) / 2) + (TILE_WIDTH / 2)

GRID_CENTER_Y = (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - ((GRID_HEIGHT * TILE_HEIGHT) / 2)
```

I then move the camera using this function :

```
public void Move(float SPEED_X, float SPEED_Y)
{
   CAMERA_X += (SPEED_X * 10) * DELTA_TIME;
   CAMERA_Y += (SPEED_Y * 10) * DELTA_TIME;
   
   DIST_X = CAMERA_X / SPEED_X;
   DIST_Y = CAMERA_Y  / SPEED_Y;
   //Tried to use this for the offsets.. doesnt work
   //also tried to divide camera's x & y position by tile size , not working..
}
```

Then I update the grid image I drew tiles on as such :

```
GRID_X  = CAMERA_X + GRID_CENTER_X;
GRID_Y  = CAMERA_Y + GRID_CENTER_Y;

if(CAMERA_X >= TILE_WIDTH * 10 || CAMERA_X <= - TILE_WIDTH * 10) CAMERA_X = 0;

if(CAMERA_Y >= TILE_HEIGHT * 10 || CAMERA_Y <= - TILE_HEIGHT * 10) CAMERA_Y = 0;
```

> It gives the illusion of the grid being infinite but i just move it back
> to its anterior position once it reached a certain distance.

Tiles that I draw using this formula **(Cell2World)**

```
TILE_X = TILE_I * TILE_WIDTH;
TILE_Y = TILE_J * TILE_HEIGHT;
```

**When camera is not moving tile section works great** with the following formula **(World2Cell)**

```
TILE_I = WORLD_X / TILE_WIDTH;
TILE_J = WORLD_Y / TILE_HEIGHT;
```

---

Here is how i place an image to the cursor position for tile selection :

```
CURSOR_I = CURSOR_X / TILE_WIDTH;
CURSOR_J = CURSOR_Y / TILE_HEIGHT;

CURSOR_X = CURSOR_I * TILE_WIDTH;
CURSOR_Y = CURSOR_J * TILE_HEIGHT;
```

which is basically

```
CURSOR_X = Cell2World(World2Cell(mousePosition)).X;
CURSOR_Y = Cell2World(World2Cell(mousePosition)).Y;
```

---

**What should I add to World2Cell to include the grid/camera offsets and such, place the cursor at the right position to perform tile selection ?**

[tile selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOmdH.png)

Comment: Can you provide the entire code of the Game class? I want to check the full implementation of your camera as well.

Comment: @AzuxirenLeadGuy sadly they will close the question if I do so. You can only have minimal code on stack overflow. Basically I made a class node and the grid, the camera it is all just heriting from node and has a transform child node. Everything gets rendered based on its transform.

The game class renders things as such :
`
 (...)

 if(scenes.Get<Scene>(currentScene).active)
{
          foreach(Node node in scenes.Get<Scene>(currentScene).GetChilds())
                     if(node.active && node.Get<Renderer>() != null) node.Get<Renderer>().Render();
          (...)
}`

Comment: @AzuxirenLeadGuy the class camera is really short and 99% is what you see described here. The function moves its transform. These coordinates are then added to the grid to move it around. The grid reset them to give the false impression of infinity.